# Fractional Brownian motion references

Tags: brownian-motion

Does anyone know any good references to understand the fractional Brownian motion and its numerical simulation, preferably applied to finance.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

1. [A note on the use of fractional Brownian motion for financial modeling](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999312002787)

> **Abstract**
>
> In the second part of the past decade, the usage of fractional
>   Brownian motion for financial models was stuck. The favorable
>   time-series properties of fractional Brownian motion exhibiting
>   long-range dependence came along with an apparently insuperable
>   shortcoming: the existence of arbitrage. Within the last two years,
>   several new models using fractional Brownian motion have been
>   published. However, still the problem remains unsolved whether such
>   models are reasonable choices from an economic perspective.
>
> In this article, we take on a straightforward mathematical argument in
>   order to clarify when and why fractional Brownian motion is suited for
>   economic modeling: We provide a fractional analog to the work of Sethi
>   and Lehoczky (1981) thereby confirming that fractional Brownian motion
>   and continuous tradability are incompatible. In the light of a market
>   microstructure perspective to fractional Brownian motion, it becomes
>   clear that the correct usage of fractional Brownian motion inherently
>   implies dynamic market incompleteness.

2. Also, from Columbia: [Simulation of fractional Brownian Motion](http://www.columbia.edu/~ad3217/fbm/thesisold.pdf) (this one is a pdf you can just access online).

also see https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/j.econmod.2012.09.003 to access the first paper